# How to pass url into form and post to database using c# and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to take in a number of variables from a clients website by giving them the url format. When they submit the values needed into the url and visit my url, a form is automatically populated with these values and submited to my server and database.

I am trying to do this using asp.net webforms. Could anyone suggest resources or tips on how to do this because I am stuck and my research is turning up nothing.

I figure I can get the url values using jquery and then write up all the functionality that needs to take place in the c# code.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it more clear: do you want to create a page that can receive  data from querystring, populate data to form fields and autopost it on document load event?

If so:

- You can get and populate data on the server side with C#.
- Autopost can be done with some js script ( < body onload="document.{FORM NAME HERE}.submit()" > ).

Comment: how do you populate the data on the server side? I have the url ready to take a query string from url and it stores the values in the textboxes of form. When I submit, how do I make it store to the correct table. Sorry I am a little new with asp.net ...